# Bootstrap: Icon bar invisible only in some pages and i cant change its color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The hamburger icon bar of the menu is not visible on the homepage and about page and it is there on the other pages. It actually works when I click blindly but it is invisible. I saw some answers around here and I tried to change the navbar-toggle color and background color to black but it didnt work. I also went to .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar and nothing.
I would really appreciate some help, I'm fairy new and I dont know what else to do.
This is the html code:

```
<!-- Collapse Button Starts -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
<!-- Collapse Button Ends -->
```

Comment: The best thing to do would be to inspect the code in the browser to see if it is not maybe a css color issue. https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549  If you still don't come right maybe share your css as well.

Comment: @Brian thanks a lot! I used inspect element and I noticed that the <span> tags with the icon bar class were missing in the homepage and about page.